# Crop or pad image using react and then upload to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My web app built with react needs to upload images to a Django server. The upload process is okay except that the server expects square images. I know how to pad or crop the image using python on the server-side, but I feel it is better to do this kind of computations on the client-side. Could anyone points me to some image cropping, padding tools on react framework like PIL, numpy or cv2 in python.

Comment: Try to ask a question in the title. It will catch more users and they can try to answer. If the title is not appropriate then, the users may skip it considering they might not know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the package, [react-image-crop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop).

This can provide a UI that can crop the image as we want. You can review the code in the working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-crop-demo-with-react-hooks-y831o).